# How can i solve the classification's problem with cross validation in LogisticRegression?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, cross-validation

- I want to make a data frame with most repeated word in sentences and make a classification via `Logistic-Regression`.
- I tried to write the steps clearly in codes.
- The column `B` is my target.

#### What I have: (Sample)

```
raw_data={"A":["This is yellow","That is green","These are orange","This is a pen","This is an Orange"],
          "B":["Yes","No","Yes","No","No"]   }
df=pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df
```

```
    A                   B
0   This is yellow      Yes
1   That is green       No
2   These are orange    Yes
3   This is a pen       No
4   This is an Orange   No
```

#### What I did:

```
### 1-Import Libraries:
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

### 2- Create data set:
raw_data={"A":["This is yellow","That is green","These are orange","This is a pen","This is an Orange"],
          "B":["Yes","No","Yes","No","No"]   }
df=pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df


          A              B
0   This is yellow      Yes
1   That is green       No
2   These are orange    Yes
3   This is a pen       No
4   This is an Orange   No

### 3- Count the word and charachters 
df['word_count'] = df['A'].agg(lambda x: len(x.split(" ")))
df['char_count'] = df['A'].agg(lambda x:len(x))
df
             A         B    word_count  char_count
0   This is yellow     Yes  3           14
1   That is green      No   3           13
2   These are orange   Yes  3           16
3   This is a pen      No   4           13
4   This is an Orange  No   4           17

### 4- Count the most repeated words in column "A"
df_word_count=pd.DataFrame(df.A.str.split('').explode().value_counts()).reset_index().rename({'index':"A,"A":"Count"},axis=1)
display(df_word_count)
list_word_count=list(df_word_count["A"])
len(list_word_count)

    A       Count
0   is      4
1   This    3
2   yellow  1
3   These   1
4   orange  1
5   green   1
6   That    1
7   are     1
8   a       1
9   pen     1
10  Orange  1
11  an      1

### 5- Make a ZERO-Matrix
allfeatures=np.zeros((df.shape[0],len(list_word_count)))
allfeatures.shape

### 6- Create a data frame
for i in range(len(list_word_count)):
  allfeatures[:,i]=df['A'].agg(lambda x:x.split().count(list_word_count[i]))
Complete_data=pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(allfeatures)],axis=1)
display(Complete_data)

           A            B   word_count  char_count  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   This is yellow      Yes 3           14          1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   That is green       No  3           13          1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   These are orange    Yes 3           16          0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   This is a pen       No  4           13          1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
4   This is an Orange   No  4           17          1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0


### 7- change columns name from list
#This creates a list of the words 
l = list(df_word_count["A"])

l.insert(0,"char_count")
l.insert(0,"word_count")
l.insert(0,"B")
l.insert(0,"A")    
# Finally, I rename all the columns with the names that I have in the list l
Complete_data.columns = l

### 8- Define X and Y
x=Complete_data.drop(["A","B"],axis=1) # Features
y=Complete_data["B"] # Target


### 9- Encoding of Target
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)


### 10- Train|Test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

### 11- Import Sklearn needed packages
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

### 12- Prediction and Regression with Cross-Validation
LogReg=LogisticRegression()
LogReg.fit(x_train,y_train)

cv_LogReg=cross_val_score(LogReg,x_train,y_train,cv=2)
cv_LogReg_pred=cross_val_predict(LogReg,x_train,y_train,cv=2)

print("Score: ",r2_score(y_train,cv_LogReg_pred))
```

#### Error:

The Algorithm can't find any classification (0,1), although I used the `LabelEncoder`

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-2d7e54ebfd6c> in <module>
      4 #LogReg_pred=LogReg.predict(x_test)
      5 cv_LogReg=cross_val_score(LogReg,x_train,y_train,cv=2)
----> 6 cv_LogReg_pred=cross_val_predict(LogReg,x_train,y_train,cv=2)
      7 
      8 print("Score: ",r2_score(y_train,cv_LogReg_pred))

.
.
.

This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 0
```

I don't know what I did wrong ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing cross validation on a sample, while choosing a sample it is dividing in such a way that the sample contains only one class hence you are getting that error.  If you have more data , you should not get this error. I have performed simple Logistic regression on these 5 records and I am able to create a model  so can you increase your data and check?
I have added data like this:

> #### 2- Create data set:
>
> raw_data={"A":["This is yellow","That is green","These are orange","This > is a pen","This is an Orange",
> "This  yllow","That  geen","These  ornge","This  a >pn","This  an Ornge"],
> "B":["Yes","No","Yes","No","No",
> "Yes","No","Yes","No","No"]   }

And one more thing, I changed the r2_score in the last line to accuracy score.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. You have right, but I made this sample dataset only for presentation, else my data is 4 GiB.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the fact that your `y_train` dataset (or one of the folds) only contains one class, in this case all examples are of class 0. See also [this stackexchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870475/9435355). You could solve this by increasing the number of samples (lower chance of having all samples of the same class) or using a stratified data split/cross validation strategy to make sure that the number of samples with value 0 and 1 are roughly the same between all subsets.

Comment: Thank u for the answer. Actually my data set is 1000000 x 10101100010. that was only a sample of the same problem what i have